# HTML ie10 & ie11 compatibility?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I would like to make my website compatible with all types of internet explorer, as at the moment it is only compatible with IE6, and glitches a lot in newer versions. How can I do this? I understand it has something to do with the code below that I found in a file named "ie6.css". Tha code is below.

```
/* IE6 specific styles */
.extra-wrap, .news li {zoom:1;}
```

Comment: I would suggest you start over with standards-compliant code for HTML5 and then add in support for older browsers as needed. Do you have a need to support ie6?

Comment: I also have this code on each page of the website.

Comment: <!--[if lt IE 7]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/ie6.css" type="text/css" media="all">
  <![endif]-->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/IE9.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

Comment: No, I do not have a need for support for ie6. I really need support for ie9,10 & 11 as these are the most frequently used where I go. This is a Cambridge nationals GCSE project, so I need my teacher to be able to view it at school, so I need these modern browsers support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, make sure you have a valid `<!DOCTYPE>`. That's the number 1 reason for browser glitches between different browsers/versions.

If you don't have a doctype declaration at the top of your page, the browser will go into Quirks mode, which *will* cause you problems.

Give it a valid doctype (best go with `<!DOCTYPE html>`). That might cause other issues in the short term, but once you've fixed those it will be much better at working properly cross-browser.

Secondly, does it work in other browsers (Firefox, Chrome, etc)? Modern IE versions are generally standards compliant, so if it works in other browsers it should work in IE10/11. If it works in other browsers and not IE11, then you probably have some IE-specific hacks that were needed for older IE version but don't need to be there for newer versions. Get rid of those.

Comment: I have the `<!DOCTYPE html>`already, Yes it works perfectly on chrome, and on IE10/11. What i now realize is the problem is that my school internet is IE9, and it does not work on here. Any suggestions for that?